# Installing Ruby on rails delayed job plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-plugins

I used the above mentioned collective idea's delayed_job plugin.

according to the Railscast by Ryan beats..

1.) I installed the plugin... on my widows machine.. 2.) When i do ruby script/generate delayed_job

i get an error saying "Couldnt find 'delayed_job' generator .....

Please help.

Thanks Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Go to the gems directory where `delayed_job` is installed.
2. There should be a directory called `generators` in there somewhere. Go into this `generators` directory.
3. Copy all files/folders ( Ctrl+C )
4. Go to Rails generators folder:
   `....some path..\rails-x.xxx.xxxx\lib\rails_generator\generators\components`
5. Paste the copied folders/files there.